# Need a workaround for allowing Partner Portal users to save attachments on outgoing email

Tags: email, partner-portal

When Partner Portal users send email, unlike 'internal' users, an EmailMessages record is not created. While the text of the email is saved as an activity, there is only a text reference to the name of any attachments sent, the actual files are not saved.

This is a feature of Partner Portal.

While we can instruct users to upload the email attachments to a related record, this is not acceptable for audit and compliance.

Has anyone been able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attachments from portal user emails are not stored apparently due to storage constraints.

Please see:
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Attachment-used-in-email-template-is-not-saved/m-p/282313#M35952

**Possible workaround using APEX:**
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Emailing-an-attachment/td-p/478097

Comment: I agree with the assessment, this restriction could be worked around via custom code although it would be a bit of work.